# Imprimir una lista sin corchetes

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, numpy

He creado un array de una columna llamada **numbers**, cada fila que quiero imprimir busco que lo haga sin corchetes y con su respectivo número de fila, para ello he utilizado un bucle **for** y la instrucción **print**, (comparto el código abajo).

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([[5.1],
                    [6.2],
                    [1.4],
                    [2.7],
                    [3.2],
                    [5.8]])

for i in range(len(numbers)):

    print('\n', 'The numbers are: ', '\n', '\n', i+1, '----------------', numbers)
```

El problema es que si ejecuto esto, el bucle repite la impresión del array **i** veces y con corchetes.

El resultado que busco es algo así:

```
 The numbers are:  

 1 ---------------- 5.1
 2 ---------------- 6.2
 3 ---------------- 1.4
 4 ---------------- 2.7
 5 ---------------- 3.2
 6 ---------------- 5.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que no estás desempaquetando correctamente los valores:

```
print('The numbers are: ')
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print('----------------', numbers[i][0])
```

Con `numbers[i]` obtienes el elemento `i` que es una lista de un único elemento, entonces con `numbers[i][0]` obtienes el valor en sí.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su aporte, veo que el como desempaquetar valores es muy importante, he aprendido algo nuevo. Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción algo más eficiente y más pitónica que usar `range` si solo vas a leer del array es usar un iterador con `for in` y `enumerate`:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([[5.1],
                    [6.2],
                    [1.4],
                    [2.7],
                    [3.2],
                    [5.8]])

print(f'The numbers are:\n')
for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    print(f"{i} ---------------- {number[0]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Como tienes una arreglo 1-dimensional, podrías usar la función .ravel() de Numpy

```
numbers = np.array([[5.1],
                    [6.2],
                    [1.4],
                    [2.7],
                    [3.2],
                    [5.8]])

numbers = np.array(numbers).ravel()

for i in range(len(numbers)):

    print('\n', 'The numbers are: ', '\n', '\n', i+1, '----------------', numbers[i])
```

Si tienes mayores dimensiones también puedes probar con .flatten()